# Update single Item in Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hey Guys I need to Update Single item in FlatList data . i want to count items in a cart.
when i click on + or - in that there's no change in it. but when i use extradata prop of flat list its change in all count..

```
    class Cart extends Component {
    state:
      {
         count:0
      }


   render() {
    const cartcount = <View style= {{height:40,
                                     flexDirection:'row',
                                     justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>
                           {this.setState({
        count: this.state.count-1
      })}}>
        <Text>-</Text></TouchableOpacity><Text
        > { this.state.count >=0 && this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: 1 }</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>
                            {this.setState({ count: this.state.count+1})}}><Text>+</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>;

return (

<FlatList data={this.state.cart}
        renderItem={({item,index}) =>
                      <View>{ cartcount }</View>
    />
```

Comment: Are you saying count(state variable) is not getting updated on click of + or  - ?

Comment: state is updating but when i click it render all the list and count+1 in all the list items with using extradata , but when i cant use extradata it cant do anything